# Filter by string size in realm - Android

Tags: java, android, realm

I want to do a query in Realm but filtering from a field's length. Something like this:

```
Realm.getDefaultInstance()
        .where(Person.class)
        .greaterThan("name.length", 10)
        .findAll()
```

I did not find anything related to it. Does someone knows a good solution to this problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi I checked the documentation for you and I couldn't find anything. The NSPredicate Cheatsheet at https://realm.io/news/nspredicate-cheatsheet/ (used for Realm in Swift) also doesn't mention any such thing. Perhaps inefficient, but I did notice an option to use a regex. Could you match the string with a regex that checks string length? Eg `/^[a-zA-Z]{10,}$/`

Comment: Yes that should work! Unfortunately, my Realm version is not updated, so I cannot use the like method for while until we decide to update.

Comment: @nbokmans you can't evaluate a regex with realm-android yet as query

Answer (score 1):

1.) `Realm.getDefaultInstance().where(...` this construct opens a Realm instance that you'll never be able to close, so don't do that.

2.) Create a "computed property" as described [**here**](https://medium.com/@Zhuinden/designing-the-schema-of-realm-effectively-and-other-realm-tips-feb76c5b6072#.fxmu0jq9u) and do the query based on that.

```
public class Something extends RealmObject {
    private String name;
    @Index
    private int nameLength;

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.nameLength = name == null ? 0 : name.length();
    }
}
```

This solution works Realm-Java 0.88.0 and above.

Comment: Will `setName()` be called by `Realm` when let's say doing something like `realm.where(Something.class).findFrist();` If so, then this requires the setters to be written in some standard way. Right? Can you please clarify.

Comment: You call `setName()` when you assign a value to the field, and this will work, yes